# Python variable scope with specific example

Tags: python, scope

This question has been ask before, but it is not quite fit my case.

```
right = 0 
mistake = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
for i in range(test_image_batch.shape[0]): 
    plt.subplot(12,12, i+1)
    plt.imshow(test_image_batch[i])
    plt.axis('off')
    bestnum   = 0.0
    bestclass = 0

    for j in range(10):
        if bestnum < batch_prediction_array[i][j]:
            bestnum = batch_prediction_array[i][j]
            bestclass = j
    print("bestclass", bestclass) #only gives the correct maxmimum value when bestclass is declared inside the outer for loop
    if test_label[i] == bestclass:
        plt.title(cifar10_labels[bestclass])
        right += 1
    else:
        plt.title(cifar10_labels[bestclass] + "!=" + cifar10_labels[test_label[i][0]], color='#ff0000')
        mistake += 1
```

This is part of my code that search for maximum prediction value and plot it on the graph.

In my understanding, bestclass should have value of the more inner scope, so bestclass should have the same value both when bestclass is first declared inside and outside  of `for i in range(test_image_batch.shape[0]):` However, that is not the case. bestclass only gives the correct maximum value for all of batch_prediction_array[i] when it is declared inside the outer for loop. When bestclass is declared outside the outer for loop, it only print the correct maximum value for the first batch_prediction_array[i].

I am 100 percent sure that bestclass is not declared anywhere else in the code except the code shown above.

It is even more strange because I cannot reproduce the same behavior.

So my question is what did I miss? I understand LEGB rule, but in this particular case. It does not seem to follow LEGB rule.

If this helps at all, I am coming from java background.

EDIT: I just found out that when bestclass is declared outside outer for loop, if statement was skipped, but bestclass value was changed to 1. (which is `batch_prediction_array[0][3]`)

Comment: There is only one scope here, because you have no modules, functions or classes. Python does not have block scope.

Comment: Can you explain why the odd behavior? I added more information in edit section. and without the scope how can know which value of bestclass will be used?

Comment: I can't, because there is not enough information here to run the code myself.